# MOVEIT+GAZEBO: joint_states namespace and move_group problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm trying to configure moveit + gazebo, so far I managed to configure the setup assistant for a new robot as the tutorial shows.
My problem is that move_group node listen to "/joint_states" and the GAZEBO publish i with a namespace i.e /robot/joint_states.
(I figured it out by following the kinematics tutorial so as by typing "rostopic list -v").

So, my question is how do I configure move_group to listen to /robot/joint_states.

My github repository: https://github.com/nirlevi5/robo-service.git
Attached an Example rqt_graph photo.

Thanks
Nir

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208410/moveit+gazebo:-joint_states-namespace-and-move_group-problem/) by [nir](https://answers.ros.org/users/3001/nir/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-05-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A simple solution is add a remap entry on `move_group.launch`

```
<node name="move_group" ...
...
<remap from="/joint_states" to="/your_robot/joint_states" />
</node>
```

---

Originally posted by [rorromr](https://answers.ros.org/users/22334/rorromr/) with karma: 36 on 2015-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nir](https://answers.ros.org/users/3001/nir/) on 2015-05-04**:
Great, It works now.
Now the Rviz plans based on the gazebo model configuration.
But still, when I'm following the [kinematics](http://moveit.ros.org/wiki/Kinematics/C%2B%2B_API) tutorial I get joint values equals to zero, I thought it should take it from the /myrobot/joint_states topic?

**Comment by [rorromr](https://answers.ros.org/users/22334/rorromr/) on 2015-05-18**:
Currently I have the same issue, this topic shows some information about the problem
https://groups.google.com/a/rethinkrobotics.com/forum/#!topic/brr-users/P890sqFxpBo